# Understanding use vs just using function parameters in PHP, mostly in this piece of code

Tags: php

I have this code from a PHP course:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

$headers = [
    "Authorization: Client-ID YOUR_ACCESS_KEY"
];

$response_headers = [];

$header_callback = function($ch, $header) use (&$response_headers) {
    
    $len = strlen($header);
    
    $parts = explode(":", $header, 2);
    
    if (count($parts) < 2) {
        
        return $len;
    }
    
    $response_headers[$parts[0]] = trim($parts[1]);
    
    return $len;
};

curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION => $header_callback
]);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($ch);

echo $status_code, "\n";

print_r($response_headers);

echo $response, "\n";
```

I'm having a hard time understanding why the header_callback is written the way it is. Mostly because of the confusion provoked by the use keyword. I've been trying to understand it, but I'm not sure I did, I have a bit of a C/C++ background and I feel like it is something similar to variable capturing from lambda expressions in CPP.

But why do I need it in this case? Couldn't I just pass &$response_headers as a function parameter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are passing the function as a parameter for `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION`, you need to keep to the expected format of this function.

From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

> **CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION**    A callback accepting two parameters. The first
> is the cURL resource, the second is a string with the header data to
> be written. The header data must be written by this callback. Return
> the number of bytes written.

So you cannot just add parameters to the function, you have to stick to the parameters passed in and the return value.

There are other instances of callback functions needing to have certain parameters ([preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for example).

Comment: So, if I didn't have to have 2 parameters, I could've just used 3 instead of 2 and a use statement?

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu, it would be good to be able to rewrite that function and be able to just return the array rather than using it as a parameter.  The problem being that there are existing expectations in this case.